# Lag on count up timer starting

Tags: javascript, events, timer, setinterval, stopwatch

Building a simple count up timer in JavaScript.
When I click the start button there is a lag between when the button is clicked and the timer starts. Can someone please explain why this is. I am a beginner to JavaScript so I clear and simple to understand explanation would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance

```js
var startButton = document.getElementById("start");
var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");
var resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
var minutesHTML = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsHTML = document.getElementById("seconds");
var seconds = 00;
var minutes = 00;
var myTimer = false;


startButton.onclick = startTimer;
pauseButton.onclick = pauseTimer;
resetButton.onclick = resetTimer;

function startTimer () {
 
 myTimer = setInterval (function () {
  
  if (seconds < 10) {
   secondsHTML.innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
  }
  if (seconds > 9) {
   secondsHTML.innerHTML = seconds;
  }
  
  
  seconds ++;
  
  if (seconds % 60 == 0) {
   minutes ++;
   seconds = 00;
  }
  
  if (minutes < 10) {
   minutesHTML.innerHTML = "0" + minutes;
  }
  
  if (minutes >= 10) {
   minutesHTML.innerHTML = minutes;
  }
  
 }  
 , 1000)
}


function pauseTimer () {
 clearInterval(myTimer);
}

function resetTimer () {
 seconds = 00;
 minutes = 00;
 secondsHTML.innerHTML = seconds;
 minutesHTML.innerHTML = minutes;
 
 console.log(secondsHTML + minutesHTML);
 clearInterval(myTimer);

}
```

```css
body{
 background: tomato;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 font-size: 50px;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 20px;
}

.button-container {
 display: flex;
 margin: auto;
}

button {
 text-align: center;
 border: none;
 width: 20%;
 background: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>TIMER</h1>


<p>
 <span id="minutes">00</span>
 :
 <span id="seconds">00</span>
</p>


<div class="button-container">
<button id="start"><p>START</p></button>
<button id = "pause"><p>PAUSE</p></button>
<button id = "reset"><p>RESET</p></button>
</div>
```

Comment: [Reasons for delays longer than specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified)

Comment: `setTimout` and `setInterval` are not guaranteed to be accurate for the purposes of time keeping. They are meant to be a "minimum" amount of time you will wait for your callback to be executed. This is because JavaScript is single-threaded and the callback can't run until the current execution context is finished.

Comment: Please don't post to third party links when you can insert a code snippet that can run right here. 3rd party links can become unstable as time goes by and we want your question (and its code) to be relevant and understandable long into the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` waits until an interval (1000ms in your code) has passed before it runs your function for the first time.

You could call the function yourself right before you call `setInterval`. That way you get one immediate call, then one every second until the interval is cancelled.

```
function tick () {

    if (seconds < 10) {
        secondsHTML.innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
    }
    if (seconds > 9) {
        secondsHTML.innerHTML = seconds;
    }


    seconds ++;

    if (seconds % 60 == 0) {
        minutes ++;
        seconds = 00;
    }

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutesHTML.innerHTML = "0" + minutes;
    }

    if (minutes >= 10) {
        minutesHTML.innerHTML = minutes;
    }

}

function startTimer () {
    tick();   
    myTimer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
}
```